# Python Error in game: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, valueerror

I am coding a game, and I am loading in a level via csv file, and here's my code:

```
with open(f'level{level}_data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for x, row in enumerate(reader):
        for y, tile in enumerate(row):
            world_data[x][y] = int(tile)
```

But it gives me an error:

```
world_data[x][y] = int(tile)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Can someone explain to me where the error occurs? I thought it was an empty string defined in tile, but I cannot find an instance in my `.csv` file with an empty block.

Comment: Hi SirSavage, welcome to Stack Overflow. In collaboration with another editor, I've just reformatted some parts of your question, and reformatted the code. Please make sure it still matches what you intend to ask about and that the code matches what you're seeing on your own system. Feel free to [edit] to correct anything we changed to be wrong.

Comment: Regarding the substance of your question, have you checked for stray `,`'s at the end of your lines? A line like `1,2,3,` will be interpreted as having four values, the last of them empty.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is crystal clear: you're calling `int` on an empty string.

You didn't include enough code or data for us to determine how you're getting an empty string.

You can eliminate the error easily enough:

```
world_data[x][y] = int(tile) if tile else 0
```